# How do you print multiple JSON data in PHP?

Tags: php, facebook, json, facebook-fql

I have tried to print multiple JSON data to php but it wont work. This is the code:

```
$fql = "SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend where uid1 =     $user)";
$ret_obj = $facebook->api(array(
                           'method' => 'fql.query',
                           'query' => $fql,
                         ));

foreach ($ret_obj as $name) {
  $friend = $name->name;
  echo "Name: " . $friend . "<br />;
}
```

I want to display a list of my Facebook friends in the format:

```
Name: [friend's name]
Name: [friend's name]
Name: [friend's name]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps some sample output would be helpful ?  Cheers.

Comment: All I receive is Name: repeated for each friend but no name.

Comment: Did you checked the answers? I've already gave you one.

Comment: what do you get if you var_dump the complete ret_obj?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an array, not an object, use this:

```
foreach ($ret_obj as $name) {
  $friend = $name['name'];
  echo "Name: " . $friend . "<br />";
}
```

[*FQL queries return the results in an array*](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/)

Answer (score 0):

**Apparent fql does not return json data in contradiction with what the topic opener implies in the title of the topic. This answer is therefor moot.**

If it is json you're getting from facebook you need to decode that to be able to use the result as an array. Use [json_decode](http://php.net/json_decode) for that. Try a [var_dump](http://php.net/var_dump) of the decoded data to see what structure you're receiving from facebook.

```
$fql = "SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend where uid1 =     $user)";
$ret_obj = $facebook->api(array(
    'method' => 'fql.query',
    'query' => $fql,
));

var_dump(json_decode($ret_obj));
```

Comment: Facebook queries do not return json strings.

Comment: I didn't know that, the topic opener implied it did ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function.
You also can define what you want to get: object or array.